# Background image colour not changing

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

i am trying to change the background colour of the following image to match the bar colour that it is on,but it doesnt do anything.

[image]

as you can see above the ball has a white background i am trying to make it the color that the bar is on.

what i tried
option1

```
 #img{
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#f7f7f7 0,#cfcfcf 100%) //this is the same color as the tab its on
    }
```

option2

```
#img{
     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#f7f7f7 0,#cfcfcf 100%),url(./images/image.png); 
    }
```

option3

```
#img{
         colour: linear-gradient(to bottom,#f7f7f7 0,#cfcfcf 100%)
        }
```

html

```
<li  style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#f7f7f7 0,#cfcfcf 100%);box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 0 #cfcfcf;"><a href="link ">Ball<img id="img"  src="./images/image.png" /></a></li>
```

any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: try creating a demo out of it. Will get the answer more quickly.

Comment: @manishkumar — Please don't recommend the creation of live demos on external sites when [they can be included in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: You can not change the colour of an image. What you can do is You can take .png image with a transperant background to match your background colour.

Comment: can you upload the image of the ball itself?

Comment: only transparency images will accept the background color.

Comment: You can use font awesome icon if you don't used to with Photoshop http://fontawesome.io/icon/futbol-o/

Comment: @vaishalikapadia thanks,that idea worked

Comment: Happy to hear that Sarah :) Please mark my answer as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your img so it has a transparent background.

You could use the **[Luna Pic](https://www169.lunapic.com/editor/?action=transparent)** online editor for example

Answer (score 1):

The background colour of the image element is covered up by the white pixels in the image itself.

You should edit the image file to replace the white pixels with transparent pixels.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is background color of the image element is in white
>   color.

Convert your image in transparent background. 
Use *GIF, PNG, BMP, TIFF, and JPEG* format for image.

**For online image editing [Luna Pic](https://www298.lunapic.com/editor/?action=transparent)**

You can also use Photoshop or any other editor that supports transparency feature for editing image offline.

Answer (score 0):

The background color of the image is obviously fixed within the image, and if you can't alter the image, you should change the `li` background. The background gradient of your `li` should be `to right` and already reach the second color (i.e. the background color of the image)  at ca. 80% as shown below.

```css
li {
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #cfcfcf 0, #f7f7f7 80%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 0 #f7f7f7;
}

a {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="link ">Ball<img id="img"  src="http://placehold.it/100x100/f7f7f7" /></a></li>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not change the colour of .jpg image. What you can do is You can take .png image with a transparent background with help of photoshop to match your background colour

OR

You can use [font awesome icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/futbol-o/) if you are not used to with Photoshop